Calculating number of ions from counted secondary electrons (mass spectrometry)
This question is an extension of Estimating errors on mass spec intensities .
I am writing mass spec data reduction software for RGA-QMS (residual gas analysis quadrupole mass spectrometry) and I want to estimate the errors on individual intensity measurements.
One critical aspect of this is the Poisson-based counting statistics of the measured ions.
The number of electrons $n_e$ associated with a measured intensity $y$ in amperes of current is given by:
$$n_e = \frac{ty}{q}$$
where

$y$ is the measured intensity
$q$ is the charge of an electron
$t$ is the dwell time over the mass

such that the error in $y$ (as far as ion counting goes) is:
$$\varepsilon_y = \frac{t\sqrt{n_e}}{q} = \sqrt{\frac{yq}{t}}$$
however, this relationship is complicated by the use of a secondary electron multiplier (SEM), which amplifies the number of electrons reaching the detector. What we really want is the number of counted ions responsible for generating this electron beam or $n_i$, not the amplified number of electrons $n_e$.
I am therefore seeking a means of estimating the ratio of counted ions to electrons produced by the SEM. For example, let's say that we have an ion:electron ratio of 1:5 (five electrons per counted ion), then the error in $y$ becomes re-written as:
$$n_i = \frac{n_e}{5}$$
$$n_i = \frac{ty}{5q}$$
$$\varepsilon_y = \frac{t\sqrt{n_i}}{q} = \sqrt{\frac{yq}{5t}}$$
I understand that this is a difficult thing to estimate and that the calculation will be rough. I am okay with that.
Here are the parameters I have:

Ion source tuning parameters
SEM voltage
Gas standards that deliver known volumes into the system

What I do not have:

The volume of the mass spec system over which the standard gas is distributed
Total pressure or partial pressures

How can I estimate how many electrons are being produced per counted ion?
We are primarily concerned with measuring helium-3 and helium-4, however, we also measure hydrogen (2 amu) and argon-40 (40 amu). Not sure if the specific species in question plays a role.
EDIT: I don't know why this didn't occur to me before, but I think we can estimate this ratio simply by turning the damned SEM off. We can run, for example, a sequence of seven gas standards without the SEM, seven gas standards with the SEM, and take the ratio of the average fitted intensities for each mass as the amplification factor.

In the other question you mentioned that you also estimate/measure the dark noise based on  an empty reguin in the spectrum. Do the signal values show a certain discreteness in that region? You could use that to estimate an amplification factor (and it's error) for signals with low ion counts.

SEMs have high electron to ion gains, e.g., $10^6$, which depend sensitively on the high voltage applied, but also on the age of the SEM (degrading over time), so it is not possible to accurately know this number without some sort of calibration procedure.
Your use of Poisson statistics assumes you are operating in pulse-counting mode. In that case, each ion gives a pulse of electrons and the pulses are counted - the exact gain is then irrelevant except for the fact that you have some threshold level, and may have some dark current pulses not arising from real ions.
On the other hand, RGAs more often operate in current (analog) mode, where the pulses are so fast that individual pulses are not detected, but the current is just measured as a continuous current. Poisson statistics is then not applicable, and the errors will probably be Gaussian. Some RGAs have a second Faraday cup detector that accurately measures ion current but with much lower sensitivity, and can be used for calibration purposes.
There is a lot of specialized literature on these sorts of issues.

A quick look on the internet threw up this, which might be an OK starting point.

I remember that I had ion counts available when I used a mass spectrometer. Indeed, now I remember that it counted pulses and that this could be problematic with linearity between counts and signal when the signal was too strong such that pulses overlap.

You might derive the value based on the observed dispersion in your signal. If $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and we have a scaled/amplified variable $Y = kX$, then
$$\frac{\text{Var}(Y)}{\text{Mean}(Y)} = k$$
Alternatively, you can use the relationship the other way around, if you have some other means to determine $k$, then you can use the relationship to verify how well your system works. If you observe $k \approx 1$ for the ion counts, then you have little errors other than the Poisson statistics.
This does require that you have a stable signal where Poisson statistics is determining the signal to noise ratio.

Example r code applied to your data from the other question
### signal measured with 0.125 seconds dwell time
x = c(8.79109037, 9.81047258, 9.16161008, 9.20899318, 9.28723348, 9.18557998, 9.78028197, 9.12099708, 9.10378668, 9.68520487, 9.38878427, 9.72379448)/10^12

### signal measured with 40 seconds dwell time
y = c(8.1676155, 8.0311035, 8.0506375, 8.0545125, 8.0100485, 8.2227135, 8.0774045, 8.2361055, 8.3711635, 8.0967975, 8.2801175, 8.2636875)/10^13

### conversion to electron counts
### n_e = I * t * n_coulomb
x = x *0.125*6.24*10^18
y = y *40*6.24*10^18

### mean
mx = mean(x)
my = mean(y)

### computing variance based on residuals
### of a linear model, to allow a linear trend
### for longer signals you could use a kernel smoother

tx = 1:length(x)
ty = 1:length(y)
rx = residuals(lm(x~tx))
ry = residuals(lm(y~ty))
vx = sum(rx^2)/(length(x)-2)
vy = sum(ry^2)/(length(y)-2)

### dispersion factor k
vx/mx  # 8321.05
vy/my  # 28993.93

The factor is not the same for measurements at different amu. Either the multiplication is not very linear. Or the dispersion estimate is influenced by the variance in the signal not being solely determined by Poisson statistics.
If you perform these computations at different rates $\lambda$ (you can vary the dwell time) and different signal strengths, then you can analyse this.
